# Adding scrollbars to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I need to add to a JPanel two JTextArea each one with an own JScrollPane. I don't know how to do it because I don't want the scrollbars to be attached to the JPanel but to each JTextArea.
How could I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Add both textarea to different scrollpanes and then add that scrollpanes to jpanel. That is something like this:

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(firstTextArea));
panel.add(new JScrollPane(secondTextArea));
```